# <tab> inserts spaces when using snipmate; <c-n> works

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, snipmate

I am using vim 7.3 on OSX Lion. I installed snipmate from garbas/vim-snipmate on github, and it appears that `<tab>` doesn't work in certain places while `<c-n>` does.

When I try to tab-complete an existing word in the file or if I want to tab-complete something from my ctags list, all I get is spaces being added...but `<c-n>` works!

If I freely type for`<tab>`, that does work.

Why is it not completing in some cases but does in others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused, `<C-n>` and Snipmate's tab-expansion system have nothing to do with each other.

`<C-n>` is a built-in shortcut for omnicompletion: it allows you to complete what you are currently typing with other words from the currently opened buffers, and some other sources.

Snipmate's `<Tab>` expands arbitrary stubs into full snippets of code:

```
for<Tab>
```

would give you this in a JS file:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Things.length; i++) {

}
```

It's not a completion mechanism. If you don't have a language-specific snippet defined for the few letters you just typed, Snipmate won't do anything:

```
function farting(){
    return "prrt!";
}

far<Tab>
```

doesn't expand anything because you don't have a `far` snippet while omnicompletion will complete with `ting`.

Because you want your `<Tab>` to do two unrelated things you will probably need a plugin like [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643).